# What is actually a session?

Tags: session, networking

This question remains in my mind for quite a long time. I have read some descriptions about this concept ( a common one in computer networking). However, those explanations are very terminological, and I still do not get it.

Can someone help explain what is actually a session in a concise way? What purposes a session is used for? Examples and good references are helpful.

Comment: Have you read the tag description?  It's got some information.

Comment: If you hover over the tag you added to this question, you'll get the meaning of `session`. A session is exactly that, an abstract concept describing interaction between single client with the server.

Comment: I believe wikipedia does a good job of explaining the concept of session in general. Please see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Session_%28computer_science%29

Comment: I think an important concept about sessions is that you define them yourself when you write code.

Answer (score 4):

In short, it's a message interchange between two or more parts, that may be stateful or not. An example is you connecting to Amazon, storing things in your shopping cart, paying, and quitting.

A stateful session (like the previous example), may be represented in the server by an object (As Java HttpSession). However, this object is not the session but merely a representation of it's state.

For more details:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Session_(computer_science)

Answer (score 1):

In simple words, a session is conversation or dialogue between devices. You could compare a session with a telephone conversation in which a person A calls B, B when ready to talk receives the call and both A and B can now talk, this is when we can say the session is established. When either of A or B hang up, we can say that the session is terminated.

Now take a look at Wikipedia's definition -

In computer science, in particular networking, a session is a semi-permanent interactive information interchange, also known as a dialogue, a conversation or a meeting, between two or more communicating devices, or between a computer and user.

The term semi-permanent because even in your telephone conversation A is not permanently connected to B.

In Networking, session is usually maintained between a user(client) and a server. You can relate it to a simple Login scenario like Facebook, when you login, a session gets established between your machine(browser) and the server, that explains even when you open Facebook in a new tab, you are still signed in, and when you logout the session is terminated.

You could refer [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Session_%28computer_science%29) for more details.

I hope this helps.